# Integrating framework from Carthage

Tags: carthage

I am trying to integrate a Carthage framework `A` which itself imports another Carthage framework `B`.

The project that hosts framework `A` has a `Cartfile` and a demo app.  I run `carthage update` and drag the `.framework` from `Carthage/Build/iOS` into `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

When I run the demo app I get a runtime crash with `'dyld'__abort_with_payload:`.